# Sails JS - Connect to MySQL Database dynamically

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, sails.js

The idea is to have mutliple databases on my host, one for each user. In the frontend, there's a loggin form where the user input is the name of the database.

Let's say my username is JOHN, so the database I'd be using would be named "DB_JOHN". I want my backend to get the username and concatenate it to "DB_" string so I can make my dynamic connection. How would that be?

In **config/connections.js** you can find this code by default:

```
someMysqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
    user: 'YOUR_MYSQL_USER',
    password: 'YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD',
    database: 'YOUR_MYSQL_DB'
  },
```

How can I set the database, user and password attributes from the controller that is getting all these attributes?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you will have to open the connection. Though normally you'd pass in `someMysqlServer`, now you'll have to instead create one dynamically based on the `req` object.

Here's some mock code that you could have in a controller.

```
var connOpts = {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
    user: req.body.user,
    password: req.body.password,
    database: req.body.database
};

mysql(connOpts, function(err, conn) {

});
```